# how to see httpS request & headers on win?

Tags: rest, tcp, https, http-headers

I'm working on developing some tests that will work with rest api. 
I have restClient in Firefox and my eclipse where I run requests through HttpsURLConnection.
My problem is that sometimes when i send Exactly Same requests through restClient and  java - i get different responses. I’ve been having that problem forever.. 
Usually I’d find the way around after sometime. It would be super helpful If I could see requests that were sent and compare it...

I don't have adminRights on my Pc, so i was looking into some portable apps. I also have wireShark but it wouldn't help.

Comment: sniffing the wire won't help. https is ENCRYPTED content, so all you'll see in the sniffer is random-looking garbage. you need something that can intercept the data BEFORE it reaches the encryption stage (or when it comes out at the other end).

Comment: Actually, after few month after i asked it, i had some good security training, and my problem was solved there.

There is program called BurpSuite. It is a very powerful tool. It rips wire-shark apart! So all you need to do is setup your browser proxy to use this tool and burpSuite will track all the packets in and out and will decript it so you can see everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that tool, it is called burpsuite. You can install cert to your burpsuite and then once it is all set you will be able to read all requests.

http://portswigger.net/burp/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SSL private key, then you can decrypt the HTTPS packet using the Wireshark.
http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL

If not, it is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can see http headers of any website on any browser like this:

```
javascript:var req = new XMLHttpRequest();req.open('GET', document.location, false);req.send(null);var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();alert(headers);
```

Paste above code to address bar of browser and hit enter.